# SPFX get shared document URL by language

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions

I want to get the document folder path url by selected language.

For etc.

1. English - Shared%20Documents
2. German - Freigegebene%20Dokumente

So, how do we get Shared documents path according to selected language ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think the URL will be changed by culture
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/localize-web-parts

Comment: @Arun Its get change please check the attached images, Document url path get change according to default language in site.

Answer (score 2):

We cannot have document folder path URLs in multiple languages for one site. The URLs are generated as per the main language of your site that creator has selected during site creation.

It means if you have selected German during site creation, you will get URLs in German language. In the images that you have shared, please check the primary language of the site **104** it must be German language.

Here, I have created  an new site collection in German language. See below screenshot for the same:
[image]

Now, see my document library URL, it's in German language:
[image]

Comment: Yes, I agree. One site cannot be multiple URLs. I have separate sites that have built in using different language during site creation. Here what I want is way to identify the path of URL according to default language.